# time zone is not working in pytrends python

Tags: python, time, timezone-offset, google-trends

time zone is not working in pytrends python
i chenge time zone in pytrends code in doesnt chenge in the result
this my code :

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
import datetime, pytz

pytrends = TrendReq(hl="en-US",tz=210)

cat = '0'
timeframe = ['now 1-H' , 'now 4-H']
contry = 'IR'
kw_list = ['/g/122fjxp1']
pytrends.build_payload(kw_list,timeframe=timeframe[0] ,cat=cat,geo=contry)
result =pytrends.interest_over_time()
index = result.index
cet = pytz.timezone('CET')
result.index = index.tz_localize(pytz.utc).tz_convert(cet)
print(result)
```